# Hazelcast Java - Query latency maximum optimization

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache, hazelcast-imap

I am currently working on a context where the application uses Hazelcast. The paradigm used is not embedded, therefore server-client is used.

I am having a flow where on a distributed map is executed a query.
After all the optimizations I could think of, different combinations with memory format, query cache, indexes etc. The most I could achieve was around ~10 milliseconds latency, which I know it sounds fast for a single operation.

The issue is that the current application is basing some flows on microseconds latency.

**So my question is, is that kind of optimization possible for the query engine of Hazelcast.** ? Or should I try to focus on maybe updating the business code ?

I am using Hazelcast: 4.2 with a map of around 14 000 items, with a memory count (total) of around 10 MB, so not that big.
The testing is done using local workstation.

Comment: How is performance on a newer version of Hazelcast ? Same or better ? Can you try `EXPLAIN <your query>` on the query ?

Comment: The context forces me to keep this Hazelcast version. And it's not about a query in particular, because I tried this optimization for multiple queries, even really, really simple one. And the minimum latency with all the optimizations I was able to achieve was around 10 milliseconds. This makes me think that maybe it is kind of like the limit of the SQL engine of Hazelcast. This is basically what I wanted to see if it is true.

Comment: By query cache, you meant [QueryCache](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/javadoc/index.html?com/hazelcast/map/QueryCache.html)? If it is the case, it can give microseconds latency.

Comment: Yes but even with that enabled on the client side, I can only get at best a couple of milliseconds - 10 milliseconds in average for a batch of requests.

Comment: Basically the map has 14k items, memory count is 10 MB, the query is a filter of two fields. The client and hazelcast runs on localhost. The client has query cache enabled, with memory format OBJECT. The best I could get was that latency I mentioned. There is no custom or complex implementation, just a simple usage client-server of Hazelcast. Also checked in debug that it uses the query cache on client side and that it is populated, so all good.

Comment: I also have an index in the query cache for those exact two fields from the query.

Comment: Also what is odd to me is that when this code is executed on the client side:

`map.getQueryCache(name).values(somePredicate)
`

Comment: the serializer seem to be used, but the query cache has memory format as OBJECT, so not really sure why the serializer is involved.

Comment: I have some tracing enabled for debug purposes, so I saw the serializer being used for both read and write on client side when that piece of code runs. And also checked that the query cache is populated, no request seem to be made to the server cache.

Comment: With version 5.1, situation was improved and some unneeded serialization/deserialization was removed for OBJECT format.

Comment: The issue is that the project uses Spring Hazelcast repositories, and from what I saw the framework is not yet updated to be able to use the version 5.

Comment: Unfortunately it is in upgrade-it-yourself state for now, maybe you can create an issue for this on its github repo.

Comment: https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast you mean ? It's using HZ 4.2.2 but advancing wouldn't be too hard. I've logged https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/issues/257

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all the debugging, seems that the query is capped in latency in milliseconds range. Doesn't seem that there is a way to go towards microseconds in the 4.2 version. When using continous query cache, there seem to be some unnecessary serialization carried out, which in certain cases can take 30-40 percent of the total latency, but even without that the total latency will still stay in the milliseconds range.

Comment: Based on the comments, when you can advance from 4.2 you'll see the unecessary serialization be fixed.